# Update a SQL table from an AS/400 program

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I am looking for a way to update a SQL table from an AS/400 program. We have already sent data to the AS/400 and would like to push it back to SQL. We currently pull data on a schedule, but are looking for a way to get instant gratificiation by updating the table directly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you talking about syncing data between Microsoft SQL Server and the iSeries? Or just SQL update a table on the iSeries?

Comment: I want to write a record to a table in SQL

Comment: What do you mean by "push it back to SQL". SQL is a language. Do you mean that you want to update a table residing on a MS SQL Server by running a program on the 400?

Comment: What you are asking and what you are meaning seem to be two different things. Are you wanting to use the database on the same iSeries, a different iSeries, or some other SQL data base on a linux or Windows server? Each gets progressively more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you have at least 2 tools for executing a SQL statement in a DB2 for AS/400:

- "Run SQL script" from [iSeries Navigator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/rzahg/rzahginav.htm) GUI
- `STRSQL` command inside a 5250 emulator

Comment: You need to connect with the 5250 Emulator to that remote AS/400 and then you can run the `STRSQL` command, which makes you enter in a environment where you can run SQL statements (also aided).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you like to push as400 db2 data to MS SQL server, I would use java jdbc or java ORM tool.